# how to overcome System.ServiceModel.FaultException

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

While updating a service reference of my WCF client (simply by clicking Update Service Reference in Visual Studio 2008), following error occurs: **System.ServiceModel.FaultException**: The message ...

I've created ErrorServiceBehaviour class. Because such a behavior is created for error handling, IErrorHandler implementation must be applied to each ChannelDispatcher.

```
public class ErrorServiceBehaviour : Attribute, IServiceBehavior
{
   ...
   public Type FaultType
   {
      get { return _faultType; }
      set { _faultType = value; }
   }

   public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
   {
       foreach (ChannelDispatcher dispatcher in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers)
       {
           dispatcher.ErrorHandlers.Add(new ErrorHandler(_faultType));
       }
   }
}

public class ErrorHandler : IErrorHandler
{
     public ErrorHandler(Type faultType)
     {
        _faultType = faultType;         
     }
     ...
}
```

Later, I've used that behaviour by applying ErrorServiceBehavior attribute to my service class:

**[ErrorServiceBehavior(FaultType = typeof(MyServiceFault))]**

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
   ...
}
```

The thing is, when I comment out the foreach loop inside ApplyDispatchBehavior method, I get no error at all, but that is not the way out (because I want my errors to be handled).

Below there is my service config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior" name="MyService">
            <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="IMyService" bindingConfiguration="NoSecurityBinding"/>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="DefaultBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="NoSecurityBinding" >
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
                    <message establishSecurityContext="false"/>
                </security>
            </binding>
            <binding name="DefaultBinding" />
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: is your security completely off?

Comment: I don't understand.. what you saying ?

Comment: I;m very confused. Exactly _when_ do you get the fault? And please post the full message from the fault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace in your code and try:

```
<bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="NoSecurityBinding" >
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
                    <message clientCredentialType="None"/>
                </security>
            </binding>
            <binding name="DefaultBinding" />
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```